# Required and Optional Arguments Using Boost Library Program Options

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options, required, option-type

I'm using Boost Program Options Library to parse the command line arguments.

I have the following requirements:

1. Once "help" is provided, all the other options are optional;
2. Once "help" is not provided, all the other options are required.

How I can deal with this?  Here is the my code handling this, and I found it's very redundant, and I think there must be an easy to do, right?

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
namespace po = boost::program_options;

bool process_command_line(int argc, char** argv,
                          std::string& host,
                          std::string& port,
                          std::string& configDir)
{
    int iport;

    try
    {
        po::options_description desc("Program Usage", 1024, 512);
        desc.add_options()
          ("help",     "produce help message")
          ("host,h",   po::value<std::string>(&host),      "set the host server")
          ("port,p",   po::value<int>(&iport),             "set the server port")
          ("config,c", po::value<std::string>(&configDir), "set the config path")
        ;

        po::variables_map vm;
        po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
        po::notify(vm);

        if (vm.count("help"))
        {
            std::cout << desc << "\n";
            return false;
        }

        // There must be an easy way to handle the relationship between the
        // option "help" and "host"-"port"-"config"
        if (vm.count("host"))
        {
            std::cout << "host:   " << vm["host"].as<std::string>() << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "\"host\" is required!" << "\n";
            return false;
        }

        if (vm.count("port"))
        {
            std::cout << "port:   " << vm["port"].as<int>() << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "\"port\" is required!" << "\n";
            return false;
        }

        if (vm.count("config"))
        {
            std::cout << "config: " << vm["config"].as<std::string>() << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "\"config\" is required!" << "\n";
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << "\n";
        return false;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cerr << "Unknown error!" << "\n";
        return false;
    }

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << iport;
    port = ss.str();

    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  std::string host;
  std::string port;
  std::string configDir;

  bool result = process_command_line(argc, argv, host, port, configDir);
  if (!result)
      return 1;

  // Do the main routine here
}
```

Answer (score 115, accepted):

I've run into this issue myself.  The key to a solution is that the function `po::store` populates the `variables_map` while `po::notify` raises any errors encountered, so `vm` can be used prior to any notifications being sent.

So, as per [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395503/required-and-optional-arguments-using-boost-library-program-options/5517313#5517313), set each option to required, as desired, but run `po::notify(vm)`  after you've dealt with the help option.  This way it will exit without any exceptions thrown.  Now, with the options set to required, a missing option will cause a [`required_option`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost/program_options/required_option.html) exception to be thrown and using its `get_option_name` method you can reduce your error code to a relatively simple `catch` block.

As an additional note, your option variables are set directly via the `po::value< -type- >( &var_name )` mechanism, so you don't have to access them through `vm["opt_name"].as< -type- >()`.

A **code example** is provided in [Peters answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5519200/198315)

Comment: thanks for your reply.  I think it works as expected.  I have also posted the complete program below for the folks who need a good example.

Comment: Excellent solution! The official documentation should make it clear with an example.

Comment: @rcollyer could you provide a full working example, please?

Comment: @JonasStein I could, but [Peter's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5519200/198315) appears to be just fine. Let me know if that is insufficient.

Comment: @rcollyer The sx website does not visually connect the two answers, so I missed that. I have added a note. Please revert, if you are not comfortable with it.

Answer (score 56):

Here is complete program as per rcollyer and Tim, whom the credits go to:

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
namespace po = boost::program_options;

bool process_command_line(int argc, char** argv,
                          std::string& host,
                          std::string& port,
                          std::string& configDir)
{
    int iport;

    try
    {
        po::options_description desc("Program Usage", 1024, 512);
        desc.add_options()
          ("help",     "produce help message")
          ("host,h",   po::value<std::string>(&host)->required(),      "set the host server")
          ("port,p",   po::value<int>(&iport)->required(),             "set the server port")
          ("config,c", po::value<std::string>(&configDir)->required(), "set the config path")
        ;

        po::variables_map vm;
        po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);

        if (vm.count("help"))
        {
            std::cout << desc << "\n";
            return false;
        }

        // There must be an easy way to handle the relationship between the
        // option "help" and "host"-"port"-"config"
        // Yes, the magic is putting the po::notify after "help" option check
        po::notify(vm);
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << "\n";
        return false;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cerr << "Unknown error!" << "\n";
        return false;
    }

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << iport;
    port = ss.str();

    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  std::string host;
  std::string port;
  std::string configDir;

  bool result = process_command_line(argc, argv, host, port, configDir);
  if (!result)
      return 1;

  // else
  std::cout << "host:\t"   << host      << "\n";
  std::cout << "port:\t"   << port      << "\n";
  std::cout << "config:\t" << configDir << "\n";

  // Do the main routine here
}

/* Sample output:

C:\Debug>boost.exe --help
Program Usage:
  --help                produce help message
  -h [ --host ] arg     set the host server
  -p [ --port ] arg     set the server port
  -c [ --config ] arg   set the config path


C:\Debug>boost.exe
Error: missing required option config

C:\Debug>boost.exe --host localhost
Error: missing required option config

C:\Debug>boost.exe --config .
Error: missing required option host

C:\Debug>boost.exe --config . --help
Program Usage:
  --help                produce help message
  -h [ --host ] arg     set the host server
  -p [ --port ] arg     set the server port
  -c [ --config ] arg   set the config path


C:\Debug>boost.exe --host 127.0.0.1 --port 31528 --config .
host:   127.0.0.1
port:   31528
config: .

C:\Debug>boost.exe -h 127.0.0.1 -p 31528 -c .
host:   127.0.0.1
port:   31528
config: .
*/
```

Comment: You should catch `boost::program_options::required_option` so that you can handle the lack of a required option directly instead of having it caught by `std::exception`.

Comment: Port should be of type unsigned.

Comment: You should catch boost::program_options::error this only.

Comment: I agree with rcollyer. You can also print the missing option in that specific catch block along with the usage info.  It's standard for apps to print the usage info when the command line is incorrect. I wish boost would output something in the usage what is or isn't required, but it doesn't look like it does.  Therefore it looks like we have to add something like [required] into the usage string ourselves. That makes using the required() method less attractive to me.  Another option might be to use boost::optional<T> and then write a validation sub-routine using those variables.

Answer (score 13):

You can specify that an option is required easily enough [[1](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/typed_value.html)], e.g.,:

```
..., value<string>()->required(), ...
```

but as far as I know there's no way to represent relationships between different options to the program_options library.

One possibility is to parse the command line multiple times with different option sets, then if you've already checked for "help" you can parse again with the three other options all set as required.  I'm not sure I'd consider that an improvement over what you have, though.

Comment: yes, u r right that I could put `->required()`, but then the user cannot get the help info by `--help` (without providing all other required options), because other options are required.

Comment: @Peter You would look for *only* help the first time, the other options wouldn't even be in the list.  Then, if they didn't pass in the help option, only then would you run the parsing again, this time passing in the other three options, set to required, and *not* help.  This approach would probably require a third set of options, with all of them combined, to use for printing the usage information.  I'm pretty sure it would work, but rcollyer's approach is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

```
    std::string conn_mngr_id;
    std::string conn_mngr_channel;
    int32_t priority;
    int32_t timeout;

    boost::program_options::options_description p_opts_desc("Program options");
    boost::program_options::variables_map p_opts_vm;

    try {

        p_opts_desc.add_options()
            ("help,h", "produce help message")
            ("id,i", boost::program_options::value<std::string>(&conn_mngr_id)->required(), "Id used to connect to ConnectionManager")
            ("channel,c", boost::program_options::value<std::string>(&conn_mngr_channel)->required(), "Channel to attach with ConnectionManager")
            ("priority,p", boost::program_options::value<int>(&priority)->default_value(1), "Channel to attach with ConnectionManager")
            ("timeout,t", boost::program_options::value<int>(&timeout)->default_value(15000), "Channel to attach with ConnectionManager")
        ;

        boost::program_options::store(boost::program_options::parse_command_line(argc, argv, p_opts_desc), p_opts_vm);

        boost::program_options::notify(p_opts_vm);

        if (p_opts_vm.count("help")) {
            std::cout << p_opts_desc << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

    } catch (const boost::program_options::required_option & e) {
        if (p_opts_vm.count("help")) {
            std::cout << p_opts_desc << std::endl;
            return 1;
        } else {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That is certainly an interesting alternative. But, it forces you to repeat the help handling code, and while small, I'd tend to avoid it.