# Boost:;program_options 1.49 - can't link with -lboost_program_options

Tags: c++, boost, debian, raspbian, boost-program-options

I'm attempting my first use of Boost anything so I thought I'd start with program_options.  I'm developing on a Raspberry Pi running Debian Wheezy.  I started by "apt-get install libboost1.49-all" and everything seemed to install correctly.  I can see .a and .so libraries in /usr/lib.

```
/usr/lib/libboost_program_options.a
/usr/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.a -> libboost_program_options.a
/usr/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.so -> libboost_program_options.so.1.49.0
/usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so -> libboost_program_options.so.1.49.0
/usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.49.0
```

I can compile some example source I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395503/required-and-optional-arguments-using-boost-library-program-options) by using

```
g++ boost_program_options.cpp -c
```

but I cannot get anything to link.  I've tried explicitly specifying the library path using no -l and got nothing but several pages of undefined reference errors.  I tried another example code and got a compile problem that indicated to me that I wasn't using "g++ -std=c++0x" but that's not the problem either.  I'm stuck.  I've also tried

```
 g++ -std=c++0x boostme.cpp -o boostme -L/usr/lib -lboost_program_options
```

I'm just banging my head against the wall at this point.  Among the stackoverflow posts I've seen so far, I'm doing everything correctly.  My head hurts.  ;-)

Just some sample error messages below.  Still poking around.

```
/tmp/ccTbmurt.o: In function `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::~error_with_option_name()':
boostme.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options22error_with_option_nameD2Ev[_ZN5boost15program_options22error_with_option_nameD5Ev]+0x118): undefined reference to `vtable for boost::program_options::error_with_option_name'
/tmp/ccTbmurt.o: In function `boost::program_options::validation_error::validation_error(boost::program_options::validation_error::kind_t, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)':
boostme.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options16validation_errorC2ENS1_6kind_tERKSsS4_i[_ZN5boost15program_options16validation_errorC5ENS1_6kind_tERKSsS4_i]+0x30): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::validation_error::get_template(boost::program_options::validation_error::kind_t)'
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the signature of that destructor really **should** be

```
    ~error_with_option_name() throw() {}
```

I'm going to look into my crystal ball and say that - maybe - somewhere you might have `#define throw()` or similar hidden in your codebase.

That, *or* you might have conflicting version of the header files in your include paths, which do not correspond to the version of the libraries found at link time

Comment: I think that is the problem.  I thought that 1.49 was the greatest version of Boost I could have with this OS that I didn't have to build myself, but I found that 1.50 was available and I installed it.  That seems to have done the trick.  I did attempt to build 1.57 on the Pi once but it would always get to this one file that I don't remember and the compiler would sit on it forever and peg the CPU so badly that getting keystroke to the machine was darn near impossible.  I'll look around in /usr/include and see if I have any 1.57 includes around that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Hehehe. That'd be one the BGL implementation files that use Boost Spirit for parsing. Anyways, you can cross compile that, but I admit I never tried